# Inno Setup - Force desktop icon for current user, no prompt

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create a desktop icon for my app unconditionally, with no option for the user to alter that.

I was hoping some of the questions I saw here would help me (always creates a desktop icon, creates two icons, etc.), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

My code has been

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

and

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

with the removal "Tasks: desktopicon;" making me think it would do it unconditionally and with no checkbox dialog.  So far I've failed to get rid of the dialog and have it installed unconditionally.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that was the right thing to do.  I ran the wizard and blocked letting the user add a shortcut, then manually added the icon line, and it worked.  For those trying this at home, the changes to go from a desktop shortcut prompt to automatically placing it are

Remove (if it's there)

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
```

Add

```
[Icons]
...
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
```

and remove "; Tasks: desktopicon" from the end of the last change if it's present.

I ended up doing a new setup script and integrating into it.  Perhaps I had some odd directive that kept things from working for me the first time.